# Google Drive notifications for comments

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to build a tool to receive notifications from Google Drive when someone leaves a comment in a Google Doc. The closest thing I've been able to find is the [Push Notifications API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push), but that doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for.

That API appears to send notifications about changes to files. I'm interested in comments, permission requests, etc.

What I'm hoping to do is basically the same thing that [Google Drive for Slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/205875058-Google-Drive-for-Slack#manage-notifications) does with notifications, but I'd like to receive those notifications directly in my web app.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: As a workaround, how about detecting the new comments using [the time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and request to your web app? In this case, Google Apps Script is required to be used. Please think of this as just one of several workarounds. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I am open to workarounds, but I'm not working in Google Apps Script. I think managing triggers like this would be difficult to manage at a larger scale than a few docs (but please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about ``a larger scale``, for example, I think that even if you want to check whether new comments were added for several Documents, it can be achieved by only one time-driven trigger. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize. And if you don't want to use Google Apps Script, my proposal cannot be used. At that time, I have to apologize.

Comment: @Aaron were you able to find any solution? I have figure out the solution for comments, but I have no clue about permission requests.

Comment: @MukeshSharma I haven't, and I am still interested! Would you care to share your solution for comments as an answer? Perhaps with that shared knowledge, we can figure out permission requests...

Comment: We can use Push Notification api for new comments. But as we know, Push notification api only notifies whenever there is a change, but doesn't tell us what is the actual change. 
So, in this case, we can use `Drive Activity API` that can list the drive activities including comments, replies.

Comment: Also, I found out that Google and Slack has some kind of [collaboration deal](https://gsuite.google.com/slack) that allows Slack to receive special notification.
It makes me believe that the permission requests, new file shared apis are not available for everyone. :sad

Comment: I was beginning to think that the Slack integration was special... thank you for sharing what you learned!